# Can't assign to conditional expression syntax error

Tags: python

Any idea what am I doing wrong into this one line if/else conditional expression?

```
model_gender = '' if model_props.gender == 'MALE' else model_gender = ' [F]'
```

I get this error:

```
model_gender = '' if model_props.gender == 'MALE' else model_gender = ' [F]'
              ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to conditional expression
```

Comment: `model_gender = '' if model_props.gender == 'MALE' else '[F]'`…!?

Comment: It's `var = (a if cond else b)`, not `(var = a) if cond else (var = b)`.

Comment: You are right 100%!!! I am sorry for this stupid question, happened due fatigue. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
model_gender = '' if model_props.gender == 'MALE' else model_gender = ' [F]'
                                                                    ^
                                     the error should have pointed here instead
```

The syntax for a conditional expression is `A if C else B`, which is weird and different from your usual `if` statement. So the correct way to write this is not to repeat the assignment:

```
model_gender = '' if model_props.gender == 'MALE' else ' [F]'
```